# How to get list of documents in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

For accessing to collection content I need to know `{collection-name}` and `{document-key}`. 
How I can get list of all documents with their `{document-key}` in ArangoDB with http?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpDocument/WorkingWithDocuments.html#read-all-documents) there is a `GET /_api/document` request which will retrieve all documents from collection. If you specify `type=key` query string parameter then you will get response with an array of document keys.